# Why Android doesn't print the stack trace?

Tags: java, android

Even explicitly writing e.printStackTrace() it doesn't print to the console, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout `Logcat` in DDMS perspective it should be there not in the Console tab.

Or use the `ddms` command tool to read logcat.

[image]

Comment: with the ddms it will print to the console, like in the plain old java development?

Comment: No, never will print to the console.

Comment: If you're testing on hardware, there's a free app (aLogcat) that works pretty well for viewing the logs of your phone without having to be attached to DDMS.

Comment: @Tom Brito: "with the ddms it will print to the console, like in the plain old java development?" No, no more than running a Java GUI on a remote machine will print to your local machine's console in "plain old java development". Remember: your phone and your development PC are two distinct pieces of hardware. There is a LogCat tab in Eclipse (shown above), or a standalone DDMS. If you absolutely need to see LogCat output in a terminal window somewhere, use `adb logcat`. And consider using `android.util.Log` instead of `printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 2):

[`printStackTrace()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) doesn't print to the console, it prints to the standard error stream.  If you want to print to the screen, set your display text to `e.getMessage()` or `e.getStackTrace()`.  (Although I do recommend learning to debug with logcat instead.)

Answer (score 1):

use Log.X() where X is the type of error console you want(Log.e, Log.v, Log.d, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print to console on Android. You have to use Android Log class. When I have an exception and I want to print it I'm using:

```
for (StackTraceElement element : exception.getStackTrace())
    Log.e("my_tag", element.toString());
```

or you can try

```
String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(throwable);
```

And after that you can print it to Android Log.